# Example of a trivial class with more than one default constructor?

Tags: c++

§13 of C++17 standard says :

> "**A trivial class is a class that is trivially copyable and has one or more default constructors (15.1), all of which are either trivial or deleted and at least one of which is not deleted**."

I fail to come up with a good example of a trivial class for which such wording is meaningful. What is the "at least one which is not deleted" part for?. Can a trivial class's set of constructors contain more than one "not deleted" default constructor? If yes, then such "not deleted" constructors must be trivial (according to the above wording) but that seems impossible.

Comment: The dupe doesn't quote the standard, but it asks the same question. If this question is somehow different, I'll retract the dupe vote.

Comment: I think this question is different because it is related specifically to "trivial class" not just any class.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() = default;          // #1  default constructor, trivial, not deleted

    template <class... Args>
    Foo(Args...) = delete;    // #2 default constructor, deleted
};

static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<Foo>);

auto test()
{
     Foo f{}; // OK
}
```

> has one or more default constructors

Both #1 and #2 are default constructors (see [class.default.ctor])

> all of which are either trivial or deleted

#1 is trivial, #2 is deleted

> and at least one of which is not deleted

#1 is not deleted

---

> [class.default.ctor]
>
> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X for
> which each parameter that is not a function parameter pack has a
> default argument (including the case of a constructor with no
> parameters). [...]

Comment: Nice, I haven't thought about the template constructor. This example demonstrates the meaningfullness of "all of which are either trivial or deleted". But the "at least one which is not deleted" part, although logically correct, still bothers me. If there cannot be more than one trivial constructor at all times why not state that "one of the default constructors must be non-deleted" or "one the constructors must be trivial" to exclude unnecessary questioning?